# add apply coupon link to woocommerce customer payment page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have developed a system to create orders programmatically in woocommerce.  However when a customer clicks on the link to go to their payment page it does not show the 'Have a Coupon' input box.  I haven't adjusted any of the templates.

Any ideas on how I can get the coupon input box to appear on the customer payment page?

Location I am talking about is:

```
<mywebsite>/checkout/order-pay/<order_id>/?pay_for_order=true&key=<order_key>
```

Thank you for any help with this, I am struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

Payment page is an endpoint, so must apply coupon before it reaches this point